# Sublime Text 3 shortcuts not working on non-english (russian) keyboard layout

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, linux-mint

My shortcuts on  in ST3 stopped working today.
After some googling I've opened ST3 console and entered `sublime.log_input(True)` and got following results for english/russian:

```
key evt: control+k
key evt: control+л
```

But they should be the same, I think. So, there is something wrong with my system? What should I try?

P.S. I've installed some new packages for ST3 today, and also theme for my OS. Tried rollbacking everything - no results. Also tried rebooting ST3, OS. OS is Linux Mint 17.1